# Exploring Size Limitations: API Response Base64 Viewable Up to 1 MB, Rendering Challenges

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, base64

I'm currently facing a challenge in my Next.js application when attempting to upload larger images (greater than 1 MB). While the app functions smoothly with smaller images, the introduction of larger images brings about difficulties.

Previously, the issue resulted in a browser console error, specifically a GET net:ERR_INVALID_URL error. Following an update, the error is resolved, but a new challenge arises – the inability to preview large-size base64 images.

I implemented a basic workflow in the code:

1. Upload image => POST to api/ endpoint => Receive image response => Display response as a preview in the frontend.

Environment:

- Node: 18.16.1
- Next: 14.0.2
- React: 18.2.0
- React-dom: 18.2.0

While alternatives such as using other image services or multer are available, my current focus is understanding why this issue occurs.

CodeSandbox: [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-hill-zc3n65)

Primary Objectives:

- Successful image POST from Next.js API [Checked]
- Receive image from API as a response in the frontend without errors [Checked]
- Explore improved methods for rendering images or previews from Next.js API POST responses.

Update:
I've made adjustments in the `getImageBuffer` function within `api/upload/route.ts` to avoid the GET error:

```js
async function getImageBuffer(base64String: string): Promise<Buffer> {
  // Decode the base64 string
  return Buffer.from(base64String.split(",")[1], "base64");
}
```

However, an additional observation is that while the API response base64 is visible up to 1 MB, beyond this limit, the string size becomes too large, hindering complete image rendering.

Further Inquiry:
I'm also interested in optimizing image previews. After obtaining a base64 image response from the API for display on the frontend, is there a way to present a smaller-sized preview (less than 1 MB) for faster loading without compromising quality?"

Comment: Could you clarify where and how an HTTP GET operation occurs in the scenario "upload image => POST api/ endpoint => return the image response => in FE show response as a preview"? I would have thought the (preview) image would be sent back to FE in response to the POST used for the upload request. Please edit the question with any details you wish to supply rather than providing them in comments

Comment: In the scenario "upload image => POST api/ endpoint => return the image response => in FE show response as a preview," the HTTP GET operation is not explicitly mentioned. The image is expected to be sent back to the frontend in response to the POST request used for the upload. The issue seems to be related to handling the response in the frontend, especially when dealing with larger images (greater than 1 MB), leading to occasional net:ERR_INVALID_URL errors. The focus is on understanding and resolving this response handling problem rather than an explicit GET operation.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the image as a base64 encoded image data url.

This means that when you upload a 1MB image, you'll return a URL with...about 1.3million characters in it.

While there's no technical limit in the specification for maximum URL length, browsers typically have hard limits.

A few years ago, the common recommendation was to stay below 2k characters in the URL. I'm honestly surprised that Chrome gets anywhere near 1 million characters before telling you the URL is invalid.

Comment: I got that its too much load I didn't find any solution or the alternative best way to do that task, from scratch if possible

Comment: You need to return a response with `Content-Type: image/png` (or whatever image type you're using), not a base64-encoded string. Responding with an actual image will use less bandwidth (base64 uses 4 bytes to represent 3 bytes of raw data) and save you so much hassle.

Comment: For image resizing, look into https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/serverless-image-handler/ for a serverless solution, or just use the underlying open source library `sharp` if you want to resize images yourself.